# Sum of random permutation matrices

Tags: pr.probability, asymptotics, random-matrices, permutations, random-permutations

Let $A$ be a uniformly random $k\times k$ permutation matrix, and $A_1,\ldots, A_m$ be the $m$ independent copies of $A$. Here the uniform distribution is with respect to the $k!$ possible permutation matrices.

Question: Up to proper normalization factors involving $m$, what is the asymptotic distribution of $\sum_{i=1}^m A_i - \mathbf{E}(A)$ and its eigenvalues? Can we expect some kind of Gaussian approximation and eigenvalue laws?

Comment: It obviously satisfies a CLT, with the only nuisance being that the covariance matrix is singular (rank $(n-1)^2$).  If you ignore the last row and last column, which can be determined from the others, any statement of the multidimensional CLT, Edgeworth expansion (lattice version), Berry-Esseen, etc etc, you can find will apply and you can easily compute the parameters.  Hopefully someone else will answer about eigenvalues.

Comment: Asymptotically, the empirical measure of eigenvalues should behave like a sum of $m$ Haar unitaries, in the limit when $m$ is fixed and $k\to \infty$. The limit for $m$ unitaries was computed in the following paper of Basak and Dembo: https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ecp/1465315608 . Justifying this is however a challenging problem. Some partial results are available in various regimes, not all written up....